# How to change a float in a column to a string pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The state data in my Data Frame is numbered.  For example, 11 represents DC.  I want to change the 11 to DC and do it for all the states.

```
person["state"].replace({"11": "DC"}, inplace=True)
```

I though this would work but I got

Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
person["state"].astype(str).map({"11": "DC"})
```

This would give you a new column

If you need `replace`

`person["state"].replace({11:"DC"},inplace=True)`

`state` column is considered as `int`

If you want to use the string version itself, then you have to convert the column to string and then apply `replace`

```
person["state"] = person["state"].astype(str)
person["state"].replace({"11":"DC"},inplace=True)
```